# Storing Javascript console.log output to variable and then accessing that variable in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code. First section is JS code and second is HTML.

```
$('#table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
    checkedRows.push({First: row.fname, Second: row.sname});
    var test = console.log(checkedRows);
    document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML=test;
});


<p id="xyz"></p>
```

I want to basically output first and last name from table to my html page but somehow it's not working. The console.log prints just fine when selecting rows from table. Again I want to access the selected data from console.log to view on my html page.

Comment: I mean, sure, but, i don't think it'd be that useful to store `undefined` in a variable. *(console.log doesn't return anything)*

Comment: `console.log(checkedRows)` returns `undefined`, so you need to assign the value before you print it.

Comment: Just remove the console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[JSON Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** if you just want to test your Array with Objects:

```js
// Say, after several .push() our array looks like:

var checkedRows = [
  {First:"John", Second: "Doe"},
  {First:"Mary", Second: "Jane"},
];

// console.log(checkedRows);

document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(checkedRows, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="xyz"></pre>
```

If you want to print only a string like "John Doe" or "Mary Jane" than use

```
$('#table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {

    var person = {First: row.fname, Second: row.sname}; // Store data into variable

    checkedRows.push( person ); // Push person Object to checkedRows Array

    console.log( checkedRows );
    console.log( person );

    document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = person.First +" "+ person.Second ;
    // or use:
    document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = row.fname +" "+ row.sname ;
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML` can be shortened to `xyz.innerHTML`.

Comment: ^ true...I also think the syntax he used is fine, I can see people looking around for your `xyz` variable not understanding it's an element.

Comment: @connexo yes, but we should stop learning from w3schools finally ;) - You should not break your code if you introduce suddenly an `xyz` variable. Also, can you say with 100% certainty it's not a `name` (instead of `id`)? No. :)

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan it worked. Although the output is like [ {First:"John", Second: "Doe"}, {First:"Mary", Second: "Jane"}, ] anyway I can just get the values. For example I just want to print "John" "Doe" when selecting the row and not the [ {First:"John", Second: "Doe"}, ] ?

Comment: @Hari notice that I used the `<pre>` tag to get a nicely formatted output. And see my edit.